# Excel, Expand multiple ranges in one array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I have a workbook where I want to check for gaps in allocated ranges and I am struggling to build the ranges so that I can stack together the arrays.  Here is a simplified statement of what I want to achieve:

Sample data:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 9 | 10 |

What I want: An array within a single cell containing: { 1; 2; 3; 5; 6; 7; 9; 10 } which I can then process further in that same cell.

Here is an Excel formula for what I have tried so far:

```
=LET(rangeArray, {"1:3";"5:7";"9:10"},
   first, INDEX(rangeArray, 1, 1),
   firstExpanded, ROW(INDIRECT("" & first)),
   arrayExpanded_A, ROW(INDIRECT(rangeArray)),
   arrayExpanded_B, BYROW(rangeArray, LAMBDA(set, ROW(INDIRECT(set)))),
   rangeArray
)
```

In the above LET function rangeArray represents the sample and in my actual workbook I have already written the Excel functions to get me to that content. rangeArray may have one or many elements.

My plan is to use ROW(INDIRECT(...)) to expand each ranged element into a distinct array, which I can then use VSTACK to join them together to yield my objective.

| Label | Outputs | My Analysis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rangeArray | Spill function, showing the three initial array elements | Note, there could be one or many elements in the array |
| first | The first array element, as a non-array entity | If INDEX(..) does not have he `1, 1` fields, an array entity is returned and the next function errors. |
| firstExpanded | Spill of the values { 1; 2; 3 } | Proof of concept. `first` must not be an array element. |
| arrayExpanded_A | Spill of the values { 1; 5; 9 } | INDIRECT() evaluates to INDIRECT({#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}) because INDIRECT cannot take array arguments. |
| arrayExpanded_B | Spill of the values {"1:3";"5:7";"9:10"} | The LAMBDA part of this returns #VALUE!, thus only the rangeArray is returned. Why? |

In the **arrayExpanded_B** output, I think that the LAMBDA part is erroring because of a mismatch in the number of arguments, but I don't know how to fix that.

I can't help thinking that a LAMBDA function is the way to go, but I'm new to LAMBDA, and cannot see the solution yet.  Any help gladly welcome.

Regards,
Nigel

As described in the main body, I know that ROW(INDIRECT()) can expand out any single range.
I am exploring BYROW() with LAMBDA functions, but these are returning errors.
There may be other methods but I do not want to use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a way to iterate the input one by one. This can be achieved through `REDUCE()`. Try:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,{"1:3";"5:7";"9:10"},LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,LET(z,--TEXTBEFORE(y,":"),SEQUENCE(TEXTAFTER(y,":")-z+1,,z))))),1)
```

Or, a volatile version:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,{"1:3";"5:7";"9:10"},LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,ROW(INDIRECT(y))))),1)
```

**Note**: I've only use `{"1:3";"5:7";"9:10"}` since that seems to be your starting input.

Comment: Hi JvdV, I have tested both of your solutions, and in the simplified data they do indeed return the expected results, but when I Evaluate Formula, to explore how they are working, the LAMBDA components in both samples evaluate to #VALUE!.  Is that expected?

In my actual data set, the arrays are much larger, hundred and thousands of elements, and I found that the volatile version did not work on such a scale: It returned #REF!   So, it must have some limitations as to the number of elements it can process.

But, the non-volatile version is working a treat, so thank-you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
    d, B3:C5,
    DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),
            LAMBDA(a, v, VSTACK(a, SEQUENCE(INDEX(d, v, 2) - INDEX(d, v, 1) + 1, , INDEX(d, v, 1))))
        ),
        1
    )
)
```

[image]